# Addition error with ruby-1.9.2

Tags: ruby, floating-accuracy, ruby-1.9.2

When I add `0.1+0.2` I am getting `0.30000000000000004` but when I add the same number in `ruby 1.8.7` I am getting the correct answer `0.3`. I get `0.3` by rounding but I just want to get `0.3` on `ruby 1.9.2` by adding `0.1` and `0.2`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need bigdecimal for this to make work.

```
(BigDecimal('0.1') + BigDecimal("0.2")).to_f
```

See below link:

http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4394

Comment: `"since it is ruby's bug"` - this is not a bug - it's how floating point works - the bug report claiming this as a bug was marked as rejected.

Answer (score 7):

Your old ruby lied to you:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> printf("%40.40f\n", 0.1 + 0.2)
0.3000000000000000444089209850062616169453
=> nil
```

[Floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) are very tricky beasts.

Comment: That's an interesting notion: it lied to you and gave you the correct answer, it shouldn't have done that. Floating point _is_ fun!

Comment: @Andrew Marshall, thanks for the laugh. :)

Comment: I was using ruby-1.8.7-head, not patchlevel.

Comment: @Sadiksha Gautam, you get the same answer from C :) so I doubt specific patchlevel of Ruby really matters. Really, try the `printf("%40.40f\n", 0.1 + 0.2)` on any version of Ruby, Python, C, Java, etc. you can find; any language that uses IEEE-754 floating point numbers is going to give you these sorts of results.

Comment: And Python will do the same. `>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004`. It's the joy of dealing with floating point and why financial calculations don't use floats.

Comment: @sarnold => That is because you might be using some kind of formatting -- "%40.40f\n". Do "%0.2f\n" instead and you will get the right answer.

Comment: @a5his, I don't _want_ "the right answer" :) The whole point of my formatting is to help Sadiksha Gautam see that his older version of Ruby was _lying_ to him about what "the right answer" was, and rounding the results before giving him the answer.

Comment: @sarnold => Thx. I hope it helped :sadiksha